# Flutter downgrade and no connected device

Tags: android-studio, flutter, adb, device, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 4.0.2 on mac os 10.15.
Then I created a new flutter project and everything works fine with AVD.

But for development purpose I downgraded flutter to 1.17.4 and then Android Studio can't connect to virtual devices anymore even if 'flutter devices' command works and all the configuration seems fine.
I can't manage this issue after 1 full day googling and many tries :-( help would be appreciated. Thanks guy.

[image: Situation]

[image: SDK path is ok and components are installed]

Comment: I suppose you already tried "flutter clean" and "Invalidate Caches/Restart"?

Comment: thx for your suggestion, I had not tried but it changed nothing.

Comment: Tried with adb 1.0.39 and problem is still the same

Comment: I tried to reinstall a fresh download of IDE and downgraded flutter plugin to v43 but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed my problem by installing the full xcode app and cocoapods.
flutter doctor revert 'no issues'.
Everything works like a charm now.